# Extract data between two characters in multiple text file and rename them

Tags: excel, vba, export

I need some assistance to create my first VBA code.

I have thousands of text file in a folder that contain some data between the character "\" which needs to be extracted into excel.

Sample text file will look like

Values are 1.000000 1.000000 9 0 3 1 1 0 \021-03930\ \021-03930\ \C21XBH113-MD
\C21XBH113-MD2\ \A21XBS\ \A21XBS135\ \A21XBS136\ \W21XBS112\ \R21XBS112\ "Value" "Data"
"Included" 1 1 0 0

I need to export all information between "\" from multiple txt file to first column of excel (one by one).

Also once we have this information in column A, we need to replace them with other information that will be entered in column B.

```
enter code here
Sub FindAllPoints()

Dim filename As String, nextrow As Long, MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String, text As String, textline As String, filedate As String
Dim filenum As Integer
Dim idx%

MyFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "*.txt")
Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "ListofPoints"
 
  Range("A1").Value = "ListofOLDPoints"
  Range("B1").Value = "ListofNEWPoints"

nextrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Do While MyFile <> ""

    Open (MyFolder & MyFile) For Input As #1


    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline

        idx = InStr(textline, "\")
        If idx > 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(nextrow, "A").Value = Mid(textline, idx)
            nextrow = nextrow + 1
        End If
        
    Loop
    
    Close #1
    
    MyFile = Dir()

Loop
End Sub
```

My code might be wrong, please help me built a code that can do my task.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by: «Also once we have this information in column A, we need to replace them with other information that will be entered in column B.» How do you propose to associate anything that gets added to column A with whatever is in column B, given that there isn't anything in Column B? And how do you propose to re-associate the data with their original files?

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
Sub GetData()
'Note: this code requires a reference to the Word object model.
'See under the VBE's Tools|References.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strFolder As String, strFile As String
Dim WkSht As Worksheet, r As Long
strFolder = GetFolder: If strFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
Dim wdApp As New Word.Application, wdDoc As Word.Document
wdApp.Visible = False: r = 0
Set WkSht = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
With WkSht
  .Name = "ListofPoints"
  .Range("A1").Value = "ListofOLDPoints"
  .Range("B1").Value = "ListofNEWPoints"
End With
strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\*.txt", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
  r = r + 1
  Set wdDoc = .Documents.Open(Filename:=strFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False)
  With wdDoc
    With .Paragraphs.First.Range
      If InStr(.Text, "\") > 0 Then WkSht.Range("A" & r).Value = Split(.Text, "\")(1)
    End With
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
  End With
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set wdApp = Nothing: Set WkSht = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
 
Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim oFolder As Object
    GetFolder = ""
    Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
    If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
    Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

That said, it's not clear whether you have multiple such strings each each file. If so, you might replace:

```
Dim WkSht As Worksheet, r As Long
```

with:

```
Dim WkSht As Worksheet, r As Long, c as Long
```

and replace:

```
      If InStr(.Text, "\") > 0 Then WkSht.Range("A" & r).Value = Split(.Text, "\")(1)
```

with:

```
      For c = 1 To UBound(Split(.Text, "\")) - 1
        WkSht.Cells(r, c).Value = Split(.Text, "\")(c)
      Next
```